# How to set case of text in entry of table of contents independently of initially written case using KOMA-SCRIPT scrreport

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I type paragraphs uppercase, but I need them to be written in table of contents with only the first letter capitalized. I tried so:

```
\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\expandafter\MakeUppercase}
```

But I got an error, because the first character of entry is counter.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreport}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{CHAP1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please read about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). As it is, your code can't be compiled directly so it's difficult to test and modify for people willing to help you.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to simply specify two different titles, one to be used in the text and the other for the TOC? Try this: `\chapter[Chapter 1]{CHAP1}`

Comment: Yes, it is, thanks!